# Best way to display error on Slack from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-alerts, azure-monitor

What is the best way to display detailed error messages in Azure Data Factories?

1: Create a log workspace, configure Data Factories to send logs there, query it every 5 minutes using alerts, and trigger an action group through a webhook in a Logic App when the query returns a row. In the alert, I include dimensions for each column, such as start, end, and status. I then extract these dimensions from the JSON and transform them into a message in Slack.

2: Set up a 5-minute recurrence in a Logic App. Each time, query the logs with a condition "time generated >= ago(5m)." If it returns rows, post the information in Slack; otherwise, stop the execution.

Which approach would be more efficient and cost-effective?

Answer (score 0):

Integrating log analytics or application insights in alert generation is how its intended as the primary purpose, as you figured out there can be many ways of doing one thing. You can also trigger the logic app from your data factory (to be run every 5 mins as scheduled). I dont think there will be much of a cost difference between any of the solutions, as you are not spending much compute here. My personal preference would be staying with log analytics alert generation as much as possible, with use of webhooks.

learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing

On another note, usage of any low-code solution such as ADF or logic apps is supposed to make things a bit more pricey (at least in theory), but it might not matter much in the end. The least efficient one would be running the logic app from data factory on scheduled pipelines, even though you are not spending much compute. The most efficient one would be getting an alert generated once a failure is detected, such as using a webhook to send an API call to your slack, without a check that runs every 5 minutes.

Comment: Isn't that expensive? Since it will always run without failures?

Comment: @8b1tz, if you are referring to the solution with ADF pipeline, yes.

Comment: It wouldn't be a direction for the logic app of each pipeline, I would use the raw logic app to search the workspace log every 10 minutes and get the lines that failed in the meantime, then I would put everything together and alert in a single application

Comment: @8b1tz, that is fine. And it is by no means inefficient. see the template here if you havent seen it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-quickstart-templates/alert-to-slack-with-logic-app/

This doesnt involve scanning every 5 minutes as far as I can see ( at least on the log level, alert rule by itself runs a scan that you can specify). You can also just use the email address associated with that slack channel (as every channel has an email ) in the email section of the alert rule.  (then you dont need to bother with webhooks) But these are small adjustments anyway.

Comment: An alert rule with one condition costs 0.10 USD per month which is great. If you could make the process without the logic app, and only with the alert rule, by sending an email directly to your slack, you could achieve the best cost. Inclusion of a logic app would increase the price.

Comment: Besides using a unique email for the Slack channel and using that email in your Azure Monitor alert action group settings, another option could be to send the alert to your company alert email inbox and have it automatically forwarded to that Slack channel email address.

Comment: The problem is that the standard alert is not clear, our on-call staff use slack as their main tool, so it would be difficult to understand just from the message, understand?

Comment: @8b1tz, coming back to your question, since you have transformations steps in 1st option, wont you need these as well in the 2nd?